# Are the functions $f,g,h$ linearly independent? If not, find non-trivial solutions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, independence

> Are the functions $f, g, h$ given below linearly independent? If they are not linearly independent, find a nontrivial solutions to the equations below:
>
> $$f(x)=0, \quad g(x)=\cos(9x), \quad h(x)= \sin(9x)$$

My take so far is that, I have computed the Wronskian via Wolfram, and I got Wronskian as $0$, but I know these functions are linearly dependent because they are not $0$ at all $R$ but I have no idea how to find nontrivial solutions to this question. I think I should have an answer as follow:

$$C_1(0) + C_2(\cos(9x)) + C_3\sin(9x) = 0$$

Where $C$s are constant. Maybe they don't necessarily have to be constant? I'm not sure.

Could I get some help on finding those constants? I'm having a hard time finding linear combinations.

Comment: No collection of vectors that contains the zero vector, $0$, can be linearly independent, as $a \cdot 0$, for any $a \neq 0$ is a nontrivial linear combination equal to zero.

Comment: To add to Travis' answer, f(x)=0 would always give a dependent set, so why not take that function out and ask yourself: Are g(x) and h(x) linear independent? That should be doable with Wronskian...

Comment: @Travis Sorry I should've made the title clearly. I know these are lin independent, i'm having hard time finding constant values..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; since $f(x) = 0$, $\{f, g, h\}$ is *not* linearly independent.

Comment: @Travis if they are independent, (which we know they aren't) i can just use 0,0,0 as constants. but since they are not linearly independent, i want to find nontrivial soln's that satisfies equation i have above.

Comment: If the Wronskian is not 0,  what can you say about the functions?

Comment: @Allie $5\cdot f(x)+0\cdot g(x)+0\cdot h(x)=0$.  Also $8\cdot f(x)+0\cdot g(x)+0\cdot h(x)=0$.  As Travis said, $a\cdot f(x)+0\cdot g(x)+0\cdot h(x)=0$ for all values of $a$.

Comment: @Travis ahh i see. Thank you both, i got what you guys were trying to say :)

Comment: @JMoravitz if you could just type your comment as an answer, I will pick your answer (cuz i dont want this to be left out as unanswered..)

Comment: Clarify what kind of functions you are considering (domain, etc) and what kind are your scalars or constants. If not something "special" then basically you want to find out constants $a$ and $b$ with $a\cos 9x+b \sin 9x=0$ This is impossible except when $a=b=0$

Answer (score 1):

A collection $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ in a vector space $V$ is *linearly independent* if the equation
$$
\lambda_1v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nv_n=0
$$
is only solved by $\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_n=0$.

In your case, you have the collection $\{f,g,h\}$, which can be viewed as a collection in the vector space of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Now, note that
$$
1\cdot f+0\cdot g+0\cdot h=f=0
$$
Do you see why this proves that your collection is linearly dependent?